# MDX SUM function returning true

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssas, mdx, cube

I am trying to do a simple sum of 2 measures in MDX.

my query looks like this

```
[Measures].[Submissions Count] = SUM({[Measures].[Gain Count] , [Measures].[No Movement Count]}, [Measures].[Submissions Count])
```

when i brows the cube in visual studio the result displays 'True'.
It should be a numeric value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just use the `+` operator?

```
[Measures].[Submissions Count] = 
  [Measures].[Gain Count] + [Measures].[No Movement Count];
```